# PHP, cURL: logging in attempt just returns the login page

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to log in to: http://hoteladmin.laterooms.com/en/SignIn.aspx

I've researched how to use cURL and came up with this:

```
<?php

$username = 'myusername';
$password = 'mypassword';
$loginUrl = 'http://hoteladmin.laterooms.com/en/SignIn.aspx';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '_ctl1:userName='.$username.'&_ctl1:passWord='.$password.'_ctl1:btnLogin=Login');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
$store = curl_exec($ch);

?>
```

I was hoping it would log me in and print out the "successful login" page but it just prints out the "login" page.

EDIT: Following comments and more research I noticed that I was missing the "__VIEWSTATE" field in my POST. I have added this. This is the state of my code now:

```
<?php

// GRAB VIEWSTATE VALUE
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "hoteladmin.laterooms.com/en/SignIn.aspx");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);    

// grab position of __VIEWSTATE
$position = strpos($output, "id=\"__VIEWSTATE\" value=\"");

// echo at substr position
// 25
$viewStateTag = substr($output, $position, 185); 

echo $viewStateTag;
echo "<br />";
echo "<br />";
$viewState = substr($viewStateTag, 25, 148);
echo $viewState;
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------


$username = 'test';
$password = 'test';
$loginUrl = 'hoteladmin.laterooms.com/en/SignIn.aspx';

//init curl
$ch = curl_init();

//Set the URL to work with
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);

// ENABLE HTTP POST
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

//Set the post parameters
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '__VIEWSTATE=%2F' . $viewState . '&_ctl1%3AuserName=' . $username . '&_ctl1%3ApassWord=' . $password . '&_ctl1%3AbtnLogin=Login');

//Handle cookies for the login
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$store = curl_exec($ch);

echo $store;
?>
```

As you can see, I start by requesting the login page and grabbing the __VIEWSTATE value. I then try to post the full login details on the page (viewstate, username, password and login value) and echo the server response. The server response is not what I want. I get a page that contains the words "Object mover here" with a link to the login page. The page I'm expecting is the "access denied" page with is basically the login page with the sentence "No group found." added to it.

Comment: u may need to pass in more than just those info above, try an actual login using a browser with firebug or some debugging tool to see what is being passed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `__VIEWSTATE` parameter in the POST request is missing but I don't know what it is.
These are the parameters passed during my login test:

```
__VIEWSTATE:/wEPDwUJNTg3NDcxNzc1D2QWBAIGDxYCHgFzBQ1sYXRlcm9vbXMuY3NzZAIKD2QWAgIBD2QWAgIBD2QWAmYPZBYGAgMPDxYCHgRUZXh0BQVMb2dpbmRkAgQPDxYCHwEFC1NpZ24gdXAgbm93ZGQCBQ8WBB8BBQ9ObyBncm91cCBmb3VuZC4eB1Zpc2libGVnZGQ=
_ctl1:userName:test
_ctl1:passWord:test
_ctl1:btnLogin:Login
```

**EDIT**
As discovered later, the `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` cURL parameter should be set to true, in order to let cURL follow the redirects.

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't spotted that. Now that I've added the viewstate I get redirected to a page that asks me to click a link to return to the login page. Did you manage to get to the page that mentions "Group not found" (ie: access denied) or did you get to the same page as me?

Comment: Actually I copy pasted your parameters and now get directed back to the regular login page, not the "Group not found"/wrong credentials page.

Comment: I think the `__VIEWSTATE` is a parameter that is generated for each user that opens the page, so my parameter differs from yours. You should try to get the login page with cURL, extract the parameter and then use it for logging in.

Comment: Try to set CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION option to true

Comment: Thank you! I now get the access denied page. What does this option do?

Comment: The `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` option tells cURL wether it should follow the redirects or not. Without this option the returned text shows "Object moved here" because redirects are not followed.
Now you should mark this answer as the best and maybe +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use Chrome development tool or firebug to track the session ID they are giving.  I guess the session ID they give you at first is different from the one they give you  after you submit the form for the security reason.